# Flash can not be displayed normally on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, flash

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 and installed Adobe Flash. Every time flash is opened in chromium, it shows like this: [image]

[image]

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: How did you install Adobe Flash?

Comment: By using Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Does it work in Firefox?

Comment: Yes!! It works in Firefox. Maybe something wrong with Chromium?

Comment: To me it looks more like a Display Card problem rather than Flash. Do you know what graphics card you have? Nvidia? Also if you could add this info and your computer info to the question it could be helpful to try and solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this, go to the [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/) website and download it from there.

Then in Terminal type:

**64-bit**

```
cd Downloads
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

**32-bit**

```
cd Downloads
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

Flash is built in to the programme, so does not need installing separately. Also Google Chrome always updates to the latest Flash automatically.

Chromium and Chrome apart from that are virtually the same programmes.

Comment: if it still happens after this, it'll be your Graphics card settings or driver that's at fault.